# Access control with CakePHP - Restricting access by database field

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, acl, access-control

I have an application that has database records that correspond to a city, or a country.  My User model has the fields city_id and country_id.  If city_id is not zero, the user should just have access to records that correspond to that city.  There are about 8 other models with the foreign key city_id, for example, Post, Advert, Venue, Competition...

I am setting up Acl and I would like to know if there's a good way to deny access to records that don't have the same city_id as the authenticated user, unless the authenticated user has a city_id of 0 (which means they have access to every city).  The same goes to country, I have the field country_id which serves the same purpose.

Guidance would be very much appreciated, before I go and do soemthing really hacky and horrible, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do complex authorisation checks in you own function `isAuthorized()` in your controller or model. You need to set this up on the AuthComponent: `$this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';`

The CakePHP book has an [example on this.](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1275/authorize)

Comment: Hmmm... I have come across this before but I'm slightly unsure as to how to approach restricting access to certain database rows using isAuthorized.  Any pointers?